# Adding to /etc/profile.d from bash script fails

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have the following problem. I need to create system-wide `JDK_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` variables. First I want to create `/etc/profile.d/java.sh` and add
`JDK_HOME` to it. Then I want to append `JAVA_HOME` to this file. So far I have this code.

```
#!/bin/bash

create_env_var()
{
    local varname="$1"
    local varvalue="$2"
    local filename="/etc/profile.d/$3"
    if [ -e "$filename" ]; then
        echo "**ERROR: file $filename already exists"
    else
        sh -c 'echo "$varname=$varvalue" > $filename'
        chmod +x "$filename"
    fi
}

append_env_var()
{
    local varname="$1"
    local varvalue="$2"
    local filename="/etc/profile.d/$3"
    if [ ! -e "$filename" ]; then
        echo "**ERROR: file $filename not found"
    else
        sh -c 'echo "$varname=$varvalue" >> $filename'
        chmod +x "$filename"
    fi
}

create_env_var "JDK_HOME" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386" "java.sh"
append_env_var "JAVA_HOME" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386" "java.sh"

exit "$?"
```

However these lines don't work and I see the following errors:

```
sh: 1: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/profile.d/java.sh’: No such file or directory
```

Would you please show me where everything goes wrong?

Comment: The variables `varname`, `varvalue` and `filename` in this statement `'echo "$varname=$varvalue" > $filename'` are enclosed in single quotes, so they do not get expanded, use double quotes instead: `"echo $varname=$varvalue > $filename"`

Comment: Please  zhliu03 wait a moment. I'll try it

Comment: Thanx, zhliu03, you have just saved my ... How can I  mark your answer as helpful?

Comment: Well, if you think my comment is helpful, you can click the up arrow next to the comment. BTW, you can simplify the code `sh -c "echo ...` with  `echo ..` command in the script.

Comment: I see nothing. No arrows or whatever.

Comment: Do you have an answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

While you can remove the single quotes, there's no reason to create a subprocess and use `sh -c`.

change `sh -c 'echo "$varname=$varvalue" > $filename'`

to `echo "$varname=$varvalue" > $filename`

and `sh -c 'echo "$varname=$varvalue" >> $filename'`

to `echo "$varname=$varvalue" >> $filename`